# Rule of Thumb for setting smoothing parameter

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, smoothing, geostatistical-analyst

I'm trying to model some binary data (disease infections) using indicator kriging in the Geostatistical Wizard in Arc 10.3. For presentation purposes I'm using the smoothing option. Is there a rule of thumb or an equation to use to set the best smoothing factor? The default is 0.2, but is that necessarily the best? I've looked many places and have yet to find any actual guidelines this way.